# Capturing the password entered into an Excel sheet protection with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, passwords

I have a worksheet with a table in, that I have protected via a password I have defined.

I also have some VBA code running under the Worksheet_SelectionChange event which checks if the current cell is within the table, if yes it unprotects the sheet and if no it reprotects the sheet with my predfined password.

I am aware though that when inside the table (hence unprotected) the user could enter a new password for the sheet protection which will cause an error to the running of the macro.

Does anybody know if it is possible and if so how to capture the password a user enters into the sheet, that I could store into a VBA variable?

My thinking is that I could then run something further to unprotect instantly with that password and then reprotect withmy predifined one?

Thanks

Comment: Rather than unprotecting the worksheet, can you simply reduce the restrictions that the protection imposes? Even with a protected sheet, the user has the option to make changes, format, etc. You can impose and remove these restrictions without actually removing the protection

Comment: Thanks unfortunately this won't work as I am using a table on the sheet, The unfortunate thing about tables is that they do not work with protection on.